# MySQL index on datetime field not going RANGE type, instead is using INDEX type

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, mariadb

I would like to know why this index is not been used in `RANGE` type, but instead `INDEX`:

index:

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON orders(order_date);
```

query:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT order_date FROM orders 
WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-12-31 23:59:59';
```

in the output the `TYPE` column is set to `INDEX`. In my opinion, it should find the first record in the index with the date greater than the first and then go through the linked list, but if this was the case, type should be `range`, not `INDEX`.

Furthermore, also using `force index(report_ordini_per_utente_in_un_periodo)`
 on the `from` clause, the type is still `index`

I'm using MariaBD 10.1.43

Comment: I have 'range' on my both MySQL 5.7 & MadiaDB 10.1. Could you provide show create table output?

Comment: it's just a datetime field

Comment: You mean you have just one datetime column in the table?

Comment: @fifonik yes, "order_date" is just a datetime, please have a look at my own answer and try to check if also in your version ut has this behavior

Comment: Well for me it makes logical sense that datetime is not range when index because it's not unique index. lets say you have 3 with similar dates (and in this case it's the right edge of the range) so from these 3 which one do you consider edge of the actual data range? you can't say.

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili, no, the only TYPE that can be achieved with a unique constrain is "const", RANGE means that it finds the first record with that date using a B-TREE, which is built in a way that if there are more than one record with that field equals, the B-TREE leave points to the first, and at the right of that field, there is all the other that have the same value in that field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a kind of bug, because all the record i had in my database were inside that range, and so it has obviously to go through the entire index, and that why it marks the `TYPE` as `INDEX` instead of `RANGE`. More strange is that, let's say the query had `order_date between X and Y`, if all the records has date greater than X, but not all the records has the date lower than Y, it also marks it as `INDEX` and not `RANGE`

Comment: A guess:  Starting at the beginning may act differently.

Answer (score 0):

The query you provided has exactly one column.  And that column is in an index.  So, the index is "covering".  Hence the `EXPLAIN` will say `Using index`.

What is the range of dates in the table?

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and all of the `EXPLAIN` output.  There could be subtle things that were left out in your prose.

Comment: well i don't think that the number of column that that table has can be relevant, however, seems like that mariadb choose to use the whole index because there weren't that much records, and so could be easier to scan the whole index instead of using Binary search to find the first (however the dates were spread in the whole 2019 year)

Comment: The number of columns makes a big difference.  With just the one column -- the same as the `ORDER BY` column -- the query can be run entirely in the index's BTree.  If you add another column to the `SELECT`, the query plan will change, and the query will run slower.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia - And the "drill down" to find the first data is a relatively trivial part of the entire query.  You say the dates are spread over _2019_, but the query asks only for _2020_.  I am fishing for whether there are many rows involved, or perhaps none.

Comment: well ok, let's say that they were on 2020, the query run on my end was searching on the year the records are